# react-create-app static html page in public folder

Tags: html, reactjs, static, service-worker, create-react-app

I'm using react-create-app for creating a single page application. Now I have to create a legal page with static text, which I don't want to be part of the main application.

So I've added a html-page to the public folder, which then gets copied to the build directory. Unfortunately I can't link to that page in production, as it always loads the main react application, even with the correct URL for the static html page.

I believe it has something to do with the service worker. Does anybody has an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use react router, make a stateless component with the static html and just route as you would.

If you have a node or any other server serving your content, just make a route on the server directly to the other html file

The service worker don’t relate to this. The service worker is a cache manager

Comment: I'm not using react router, didn't wan't to install such a huge dependency for this use case. I've tried using a static route to that page, but the browser just shows the react application. I think it has something to do with service worker, as the problem only occurs i chrome and firefox, not in safari.

Comment: yes just comment out "registerServiceWorker()" in index.js and now it is working. Any idea on how to get this working while keeping this line in code?